# I have to run command 'sudo dhclient' after every restart or disconnecting from wifi

Tags: network-manager, internet, dhclient

I'm new to ubuntu. After installing a VPN, my internet stopped working. I searched for solutions over the internet. After a lot of trial and error, I figured that my internet started working once I run the command 'sudo dhclient' and I have enter it every time I disconnect from my wifi.

When I want to connect to different wifi than before, I have to enter 'sudo dhclient -r'. I don't understand what either of those commands does as I'm still new to ubuntu and I am trying to learn it.

I feel it is annoying to enter these commands every time. How can I make it normal?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I found guidance from [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#DHCP_problems_with_dhclient) that suggested creating the file
`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf` with the content

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

Rebooting with this configuration file generates the IPV4 addresses in the Network Manager.